# how to create user in influxdb which gets read only access to all the existing databases and also read only to the once that will be created in future

Tags: influxdb

how to create user in influxdb which gets read only access to all the existing databases and also read only to the once that will be created in future

I tried below code

```
CREATE USER username WITH PASSWORD 'password' WITH ALL PRIVILEGES
GRANT READ ON "/*" TO username
```

unfortunately, user is able to create and drop databases.

If I revoke ALL PRIVILEGES,user is not able to see any databases